# Struggling with MySQL query using joins

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables for storing information about books:

```
books
-----
id
title

authors
-------
id
name

books_to_authors
----------------
book_id
author_id
```

When a book's information is displayed, I then want to be able to select any other books by the same authors.

I have the current book id available from the first query, but I can't figure out where to start to achieve what I need as there can be multiple authors. Obviously with just one of them it would be simple, so I'm really struggling with this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this aught to do it.  Just replace the `?` with the book ID they are currently viewing and this will give you all the books by the same author.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM books b
INNER JOIN books_to_authors b2a ON b2a.book_id = b.id
WHERE b2a.author_id IN (
  SELECT author_id FROM books_to_authors WHERE book_id = ?
)
```

If you want to exclude the book they are currently viewing, you can change the query like this:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM books b
INNER JOIN books_to_authors b2a ON b2a.book_id = b.id
WHERE b2a.author_id IN (
  SELECT author_id FROM books_to_authors WHERE book_id = ?
)
AND b.id <> ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$book_id = (your code for retrieving book_id);    

$db_query = "SELECT b.*
FROM books b
INNER JOIN books_to_authors bta ON bta.book_id = b.id
WHERE bta.author_id IN (
  SELECT author_id FROM books_to_authors WHERE book_id = ".$book_id."
)";
```

I presumed that you are using php. If I'm wrong, just use SQL query string, and ignore the rest...

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the query below. I see some solutions with subqueries and I'd highly recommend not using subqueries. They are slower than running 2 queries:

1. Having the *book id* you do `SELECT author_id FROM books_to_authors WHERE book_id = '{$book_id}'`
2. Get the *author id* and then run this:

   `SELECT books.id, books.title, authors.name FROM books RIGHT JOIN books_to_authors ON books_to_authors.book_id = books.id) RIGHT JOIN authors ON (authors.id = books_to_authors.author_id) WHERE authors.id = '{$author_id}'`

Comment: Except that there can be more than one author for a given book

Comment: That's not a problem either, in the second query, `WHERE authors.id IN (".implode(',', $authorsIdArray).")` and it does the job